# Ajax function, live call?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a little box in my sidebar populated by ajax. I have 2 ajax function: one adds items to the list and the second deletes them if the user clicks on the delete button. My html is a simple unordered list like so:

```
<ul id="listaruta" class="lista">
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Everytime I call any of the two functions they will replace the ul list with an updated one (selecting the items from the database after inserting or deleting). They work fine until I want to delete right after I inserted an item to the list.

My ajax function for inserting (the other one is very similar):

```
var valor=$("#alcrearuta").attr('class');
$("#alcrearuta").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../ajax/ruta.php",
        data: "url=" + valor,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#listaruta").html(data);
        }
    });        
});
```

My ruta.php file gives me another ul list with the same structure as the original, just with the items updated.

As far as I understand this, since I update the ul via my ajax function, the other function doesn't know that the list was updated, it only "remembers" the older list so it does nothing. If I refresh the page, it wil delete with no problem. I'm guessing this would be solved by using live()? But I have no clue...

EDIT: Ok so now I can get my ajax call to work, except that when I delete right after I update, the value that I'm passing to the ruta.php file (the variable that will help me find the field I need to delete from database) will be set to 'undefined' giving me a query like so: Select id from poi where url='undefined'

Again, if I reload, it will work. The change I did to the ajax function was:

```
    $("#alcrearuta").live('click',function(){
     $.ajax({
                   ....
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are saving the value of the attribute at the beginning of the request, you should save it in the click event:

```
$("#alcrearuta").click(function(){
    var valor=$(this).attr('class');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../ajax/ruta.php",
        data: "url=" + valor,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#listaruta").html(data);
        }
    });        
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It made a difference, it now deletes, but it's getting a wrong value for valor, it's taking the url from the first item on the list instead of the one I'm clicking.

Comment: Should I maybe be using $(this).attr('class'); instead?

Comment: Yeah, that was what I needed and now it's getting the proper value. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I'll edit the response to include the $(this). As an extra recommendation, you should not have more than one item with the same id, you should use classes instead.

Comment: Yeah, I only have one #alcrearuta item per page, but maybe having a class would be more apropiate